# Creating a compose.yaml for spark + mysql and mongodb

Tags: docker

I want to create a dockerfile to incorporate these 3 things spark (scala version) and then a mysql database and also a mongodb database i am new to docker everytime i run the `docker compose up -d` the images are getting pulled again and again and the service stop withing few seconds after it starts especially the spark ...

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  spark-master:
    image: spark:3.5.0-scala2.12-java17-ubuntu
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTH_SECRET=example-secret

  spark-worker-1:
    image: spark:3.5.0-scala2.12-java17-ubuntu
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTH_SECRET=example-secret

  spark-worker-2:
    image: spark:3.5.0-scala2.12-java17-ubuntu
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTH_SECRET=example-secret

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3307"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bigdatadb
      MYSQL_USER: siddharth
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: siddharth
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: bigdatadb
```

this is the compose file i have made is it properly made ? Any improvements that can be made ?

I am trying to simulate a time series data where the data will be randomly generated by a python program and the mysql database will be updated every 15 seconds and then the spark part have to listen to the update and perform analytics thats sort of my project .... the analytics will be stored on mongodb (course requirement) and using streamlit or anyother thing i will fetch the inferences calculated from by the scala program that will be written will be plotted by python (idk if there exists something related to scala which can do the job)

Comment: You'll need to provide a minimal reproducible example for us to help you. For a start, remove the MySQL and MongoDB containers: does your compose work? No? Start only the master Spark. Also you didn't provide any log.